# How can I tell which classes Proguard warns me about?

Tags: android, proguard

I am trying to release my app and ProGuard is causing all sorts of errors with my server code so I went into the gradle console and see this:

```
Note: there were 2 references to unknown classes.
  You should check your configuration for typos.
  (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
Note: there were 26 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
  You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
  (using '-keep').
  (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
Note: there were 22 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
  You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
  (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Note: there were 15 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
  You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
  (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
  (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)
```

That's all fine and dandy, but how the heck do I know which specific references ProGuard is talking about? Surely they don't expect me to find/remember these references independently?

Answer (score 4):

In your module specific build folder, usage.txt file gets created.

```
build/outputs/mapping/release/usage.txt
```

This file contains what are all the methods removed and what are the classes effected. Make sure that any of the classes from your own project which matters are not removed.

Comment: Would your proguard rule prevent the app code from being obfuscated?

Comment: yes it keeps my code as is. Might not be the best practice. but still you can check usage.txt and see what code of yours has been removed by proguard.

Comment: I am looking through it and see it's just a huge list of methods and classes. Is there any way for me to see what specifically ProGuard was noting? It is very strange that it names 26 unkept descriptor classes yet doesn't list what they are..?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm a div. It lists the noted references/classes in the gradle console just above my posted excerpt. Sigh

Comment: if it is not listed in the log, I dont know any other way!!

Comment: okay ! but make sure  you include all the proguard rules required for each of the library and keep them in proguardrules.pro and also verify usage.txt. Some files might be deleted and might go unnoticed

Answer (score 3):

you need to add the verbose switch into the ProGuard configuration file:

```
-verbose
```

while the [ProGuard Manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/home) explains these notices - and how to fix them.

Comment: link is now broken