# Proguard failed after support library updated to 26.0.1

Tags: android, build, proguard, release, android-proguard

I have updated my support lib to 26.0.1, but release build is failed.
logs

```
Note: there were 3 references to unknown classes.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
Note: there were 63 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
      (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
Note: there were 29 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Note: there were 1 class casts of dynamically created class instances.
      You might consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes and/or
      their implementations (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclasscast)
Warning: there were 30 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
            :purplleAndroid:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
```

Not understanding due to which library proguard is failing.

[proguard file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I7OxYiQw_3ZytVswiu7MQMUQnnBEIz9ug6dIyGot6w4/edit?usp=sharing)

[app level build.gradle](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12i2-9NDf376ET07iflgdRN9OVnsmsGMH7gF8W4zMqLA/edit?usp=sharing)

[Error log](https://pastebin.com/0iwT99M3)

Comment: post your proguard rules

Comment: added progaurd file

Comment: Can you post your app level build.gradle file too?

Comment: Check out this and let me know if it works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537095/how-can-i-tell-which-classes-proguard-warns-me-about

Comment: I  am not getting any file under build/outputs/mapping/release

Answer (score 0):

It's not support library issue,
I using library called branch.io ,i am  added it's dependency end with "+".So it's updated and that has some progaurd rules.